# 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment:       

Answer (score 1):

So far no nominations.

Would people nominate themselves if there were 2 spots, so as to make it less of a contest? For sure we could use 2 new mods.

Comment: can we not nominate others?

Comment: i'd like to nominate Joe Germuska, Jan Doggen, and Stanislav Kralin.

Comment: Thank you, @albert :-). I'd like to nominate you and Jan Doggen. Your avatars are the most frequent ones [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/review).

Comment: for the record, I'll continue to be a mod (if there isn't any objection), but as far as I know, I don't have to nominate myself.

Comment: i figured you were a mod until you stepped down/lost admin rights. figure the latter would never happen.